# Design for Repetitive CRUD Operations with React and Django

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm refactoring an old Django project (E-commerce) from server side rendered pages, to using a REST API instead and a React frontend. I'm trying to take learnings from the "v1" of the app and make them better in this refactor.

Whilst there is a side to the app that offers business logic including e-commerce, payment functionality and customer facing storefront etc., the sort of "behind the scenes admin" functionality, like adding products, displaying them, adding coupons, displaying them etc., is all super repetitive.

It's practically just a bunch of different Models with various fields and it's mostly just CRUD. Nothing complex at all. In the "v1" version, I leveraged Django's built in Forms for this and with this refactored version I plan on using Django REST and leverage their Generic Views and Viewsets where possible to reduce the amount of code needed, but also to keep it clean and generic.

I'm a bit stuck on the frontend though. The idea of having to make a Create, Read, Update and Delete component for each "model" to show in the "dashboard" sounds awful. If it has to be done that way fine, but I'm wondering is there any sort of React library for something like this? Or even a design approach that dynamically generates these based on the input model and it's schema?

The only piece of "config" the UI needs is that some of the Create/Edit views might just have slightly different layouts depending on the model.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. If such a design/library doesn't exist, perhaps that is step one, if it does, fantastic!

Comment: Your question is too broad and any answer to this question are subjective. Try to look up a Django REST Framework + React tutorial. There are plenty online.

Comment: I'm sort of looking for a subjective answer to be honest. Plus, I don't need a tutorial on how to use those two libraries. I understand how they work. I believe this is more of an design question rather than specific to those two libraries.